# Woocommerce - Calculate shipping without reloading page by AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, cart

I need to calculate the cost of shipping without reloading the cart page. I'm trying to do this via AJAX but I did not succeed.

I started the code below and could not continue

```
var $warp_fragment_refresh = {
    url: wc_cart_fragments_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace( '%%endpoint%%', 'get_refreshed_fragments' ),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function( data ) {
        if ( data && data.fragments ) {

            jQuery.each(data.fragments, function(key, value){
                jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
            });

            jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragments_refreshed' );
        }
    }
};

jQuery( function( $ ){
    $('form.woocommerce-cart-form').on('submit', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(".btn-calc-ship").addClass("loading");
        var ship_calc = window.location,
            form = $(this);
        $(".btn-calc-shipp").removeClass("loading");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please better explain what you are trying to do and describe the context… Please remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*.

Comment: I need the shipping cost on the cart page to be shown without reloading the page when entering the zip code.
The code above was something that I started but did not know how to continue because I was not used to the woocommerce library

Comment: Yes but when asking a question, you need to explain the detailed context and provide all the necessary code to allow answerers to test and find out what is wrong… Now **In woocommerce cart page normally, when entering data in the shipping calculator, the page is not reloaded** as mostly everything **is Ajax powered**. So something else is making trouble in your case. So you should update your question avoiding it to be closed…

Comment: Please provide more detail on the problem. You cannot send a request to server with ajax or some error in javascript? please push F12 to see the network tab or console tab to look on more detail